# Centering jQuery UI Dialog containing a file input field does not work in FF

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, dialog

I have used extensively jQueryUi dialogs without a problem, until now.

My problem is: if I have a div with a file input field, and I want to show it with a 'slide' transition, I get following error in Firebug:

`NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO: Security Manager vetoed action arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLDivElement.compareDocumentPosition]
file:///H:/Trabajo/Layout/2012jQueryMulti/js/jquery-1.8.0.js
Line 4436`

The dialog shows up, but it is positioned to the left instead of the center.  IE works fine.

Here is an example that fails (tested with FF 14.0.1):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css"> 
    div#infoFrame { border: 2px solid black; height: 300px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="Form" method="post" action="list.do">
    <div id="infoFrame" style="display:none;">
      <input type="file" name="myFile">
    </div>  
  </form>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#infoFrame').dialog({modal: true, width: 500, show: 'slide'});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the transition from the dialog, it works just fine:

```
$('#infoFrame').dialog({modal: true, width: 500});
```

It is driving me crazy.  Any ideas?

Comment: i think your problem lies elsewhere try http://jsfiddle.net/82zw7/3/

Comment: I don't think so.  As I said, if I test with {show: 'slide'} it does not work.  After removing this last option it works fine.